# How I can center the header columns on reactable (r-package)?

Tags: r, alignment, reactable

Hi and thanks for reading me

I am working on some tables with the "reactable" package in r, but I would like to center only the headings of each column. For example:

```
library(reactable)
reactable(iris,
          defaultColDef = colDef(
            header = function(value) gsub(".", " ", value, fixed = TRUE),
            cell = function(value) format(value, nsmall = 1),
            align = "center",
            minWidth = 70,
            headerStyle = list(background = "#12a09a")
          ))
```

Apparently the option `colDef(align = "center")` centers the entire column, but is there an option to only center the title?

Comment: I assume you're the one that posted this as well? https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/195

Comment: Yes I'm a little desperate for some solution 

Answer (score 2):

i assume that you are using this tables in an R markdown document or a shiny app. In both you can override the `css` in order to left align the table text or let the default table and center the title.

In the first case you just need to add this line `.rt-align-center{text-align: left;}`.

In shiny you just need to add that to your custom `css` or use the style tag to add it inline like the example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)


ui <- fluidPage(
    # inline style tag to define table row text alignment
    tags$style(HTML(".rt-align-center {text-align: left;}")),

    titlePanel("Iris react table"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
           helpText("Nothing to see here")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            reactableOutput("table")
        )

    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderReactable({
    
        reactable(iris,
                  defaultColDef = colDef(
                      header = function(value) gsub(".", " ", value, fixed = TRUE),
                      cell = function(value) format(value, nsmall = 1),
                      align = "center",
                      minWidth = 70,
                      headerStyle = list(background = "#12a09a")
                  ))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you are working with an Rmarkdown document just add it to the html in the style tag like this:

`<style> .rt-align-center {text-align: left;} </style>`

and the result:

[image: The desired table]